# Отладка Wordpress на Netbeans

Tags: xdebug, wordpress, netbeans

Здравствуйте,

Для локальной проверки WP-сайта я установил на Windows8

- Wampserver 2.4 с XDebug
- NetBeans посл. версия.

Сайт на Wampserver запускается и работает, но режим отладки в NetBeans не работает как надо - выполнение не останавливается на точках останова, находящихся в файлах вордпреса: после захода в wp-db.php на функцию

```
function __destruct() {
    return true;
}
```

Остановок больше нет и сайт показывается в браузере. Еще вариант "проскакивания" с последней функцией function do_action в файле plugin.php, стр. 360.

Буду рад советам.

Comment: Ау! Помогите.

XDebug работает, NetBeans - тоже, но внутрь кода WP - отладчик не заходит, даже пошагово :-(.

Хоть какую-нибудь подсказку дайте, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

[@lemur](/users/20230/lemur), `__destruct()` выполняется при уничтожении объекта, в случае с wpdb это наверняка происходит при завершении скрипта вообще, и тогда после нее нечему выполняться, кроме других деструкторов.

Comment: Спасибо, Fike!

Именно так все и происходит - показывается страница.

Но почему не происходит остановок в точках останова? 
Наверное, дело в настройках.
Вот основные:
; XDEBUG Extension
zend_extension = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.5-vc11-x86_64.dll"
;
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = On
xdebug.profiler_enable = On
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = On
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:/wamp/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9000

Comment: @lemur,

> и тогда после нее нечему выполняться, кроме других деструкторов.

Comment: Спасибо, понятно.

А как остановиться раньше?
Есть какие0то тонкости в связке XDebug и NetBeans.
Я уже 5-й день в интернете пытаюсь найти ответ.
Но нужен скорее совет - от знающего человека. )).